# UTF-8 on FF cannot display french accents

Tags: encoding, utf-8

On my FF browser, the encoding is set to UTF-8. The french accents are displayed properly on all pages except one page. On the trouble page, they show up as '?' marks. When I change the encoding to western, the trouble page displays french accents properly, while the other pages now do not display french accents properly.
On IE, the setting is UTF-8 and all pages show proper french accents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the web page?

Most likely the page's own encoding is ISO 8859-1 or something similar (a pure 8-bit encoding).  Some web pages don't bother to specify their own encoding in the `Content-Type:` header, leaving the browser to guess.  Apparently in this case Internet Explorer guesses better than Firefox.

If you have the `curl` command, try `curl --head URL` to see how and whether the encoding is specified, or right-click and `View Page Info` in Firefox.

You might consider contacting the owner of the web page and asking them to set the encoding properly (or, as I'd do, just ignore it).

Comment: An HTML page can specify its charset locally via a `<meta>` tag (`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" value="text/html; charset="...">` in HTML4 and earlier, `<meta charset="...">` in HTML5) in case the HTTP `Content-Type` header is missing a charset (or to override it if it is wrong).

Comment: @Keith: Thanks for such an awesome response. The encoding is UTF-8(I did 'view page info'). The french text is being read from a properties file where it is specifed like this :D\u00e9tails(French for Details). This is UTF-16 encoding. Wonder if that causes a problem. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old post. But, I was facing the same issue and I used *htmlentities()* in php, when nothing else worked out. This solved the purpose for me, so thought of mentioning it here so that someone else can benefit from it.